# What's the easiest way to create a very simple online photo slide show?

Tags: slideshow

I'm familiar with all the online photo sharing sites like Flickr, Zenfolio, Photobucket, SmugMug, Imgur, ImageShack, Picasa, etc. but I haven't found a drop dead simple way to upload a few photos into a very simple slideshow (without extra bells and whistles) for sharing.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

I find flickr very simple in that regards. Upload your pictures, put them in a set, you've got your slideshow right there.

I'm pretty sure Picasa will let you do the same, only they call it Albums.

Sounds the easiest way to go to me.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried it out and it's pretty easy. Not quite as drop-dead simple and intuitive as I would hope, but fairly straightforward as long as one knows to use "sets" (vs. photostreams and galleries) and to find the "slideshow" button.

Comment: It seems if I set high privacy, then when I try to share the slideshow it doesn't work (no access to it) for a user who is not logged into the account.

Comment: Why would you set it as private if you wish that others could see it too?

Comment: Didn't set the slideshow as private. Set the photos in the photostream and set as private. Why would I want my family's photos to be public for everyone to see?

Comment: @Dan If you set the pics as private, use the "Share" button on the set's page to generate "guest pass" that will allow people you send the guest pass URL to to view the "private" pictures as well. If all pictures in a set are private, the set will be considered private too and will not appear on your main page.

Comment: Well for some reason, I can't share a Flickr Set with a guest pass even thought the set is marked to share with family and friends and the safety level is "safe".

Comment: @Dan the "family and friends" means the contacts you have on flickr and that you labelled as either family or friends. Since you put your pics at "Private" level, you need to generate a guest pass for all pictures, including private ones.

Comment: I generated a guess pass for the set. Didn't work.

Comment: @Dan: works for me. Click Share -> Grab the link, it should show "some of the photos in this set aren't public" and a checkbox saying "Private (only you)". Make sure the box is ticked. Also, make sure that the pics are in privacy level "Private (Only you)", not "protected: friends/family", unless you share with friends that are in your flickr contacts, and labeled as either friends or family.

Answer (score 2):

Animoto makes dead simple video slideshows, I know a lot of photographers (including myself) that use it.

http://animoto.com/

Comment: Thanks Case. Looks like those are not just plain slideshows but rather have some decoration, stylizing, etc.

Comment: Dan, there is one plain template that you can use, and you dont have to add music. I see what you are saying about them being plain, but all you literally have to do is upload the photos and the service does the rest

Answer (score 1):

[Jalbum](http://jalbum.net/) is extremely easy. You select a style, point it to a folder and it generates an album with slide-show capabilities for you. All you have to do after it to upload it to a server somewhere. Do check out their website, it illustrates things pretty well.

Adobe's Photoshop Lightroom can also create both HTML and Flash slide-shows from pretty much any set of images it already manages. Same as Jalbum, all you have to do is to upload it somewhere. Of course, if you do not use it already, it is seriously overkill.

The nice thing is that since a couple of versions, Lightroom can also upload to one of those sharing sites, including Facebook, Flicker and Smugmug. Personnally I never used these features but I cannot imagine them being hard to use.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a pure online solution rather than something that requires installing a desktop application.

Comment: Jalbum actually does not need installation, except if you download the installer. The .jar file is executable via Java. It may be possible via WebStart too but that I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://ge.tt is what you are looking for. All you do is upload some files (I think Google Chrome even supports drag-and-drop), and then send the newly created link to your intended audience.

Comment: MalwareBytes doesn't like ge.tt, it says there might be malware on the site.

Comment: Google Chrome and Microsoft IE both include a blacklist in their latest browsers, and neither complains about ge.tt. Can you give any details as to why MalwareBytes classifies the site as suspicious?

Comment: Well I can't even get to ge.tt regardless. Chrome just won't bring up the site.

Comment: Odd, I just tried and it works perfectly on Chrome here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Apple Mac/iPhone/iPad you could try to create [photo streams](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) (it's supposed to work on Windows too, but I've never tried it). I have a SmugMug site for more permanent uploads, but I use photo streams for quick sharing of a few images. Easy to create, share and then remove again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, if you have a folder which only contains images you can flick through them like a slideshow using Dropbox or Google Drive (in fact Drive will attempt to preview different file types depending on your hardware set up).

These links are then easy to share via email with friends and family. And would be inaccessible to non authenticated users.

[dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com)

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)